# Heterogenous application simulation running TOSSIM

Tags: tinyos

I'm planning on building a sensor network using at least two different applications - one application to sense and send data and another to collect data at the root of an ad-hoc network, for example.

Is it possible to simulate this in TOSSIM? The docs only show how to simulate a network running one application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this can't be done.  However, it is possible using COOJA, which is part of the [Contiki OS](http://www.contiki-os.org/).  COOJA can be used to simulate TinyOS applications compiled for the appropriate hardware.